# CSS how to revert SVG animation on mouseout from current frame

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm doing some button animation with SVG and can't make it to work exactly I want. I tried find same case but no luck. So I end up here, because I spend too much time on this already. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/wq4djg9z/2/
It works fine, but with one flaw. It's always starts animation from fixed value.

```
#button-border {
    stroke-dasharray: 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    -webkit-animation: dash-back 1.0s linear;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
#button-border:hover {
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.0s linear forwards;
    pointer-events: all;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-back {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 150;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to start animation from current animation frame when mouse out the button to smooth animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `transitions` instead of `animations` to do the reverse part ?

```css
#button-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  -webkit-animation: dash-back 1.0s linear;
  animation: dash-back 1.0s linear;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
}
#button-border:hover {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash-back {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
}
@keyframes dash-back {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100.00000" height="50.00000" id="svg1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 50" enable-background="new 0 0 100 50" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[]]>
  </style>
  <g id="button-border">
    <path class="path" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 100,50.0 0,-50.00000 -100,00.00000" id="path2983" />
    <path class="path" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 0,0 0,50 100,0" id="path2984" />
    <text x="30" y="30" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15" fill="blue">Hello</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! You saved my day, this is exactly what I wanted. But what impact transition property do to animation? And can you please explain how you figured this out? What documentation did you use?

Comment: I think that transitions somehow override animations :  E.g, if you set an animation from `100` to `0` , `3s` of duration, and a transition of `1s`, you will have your value animated from `0` to `100` in `1s`, then a jump to `33`, then the animation to `0` in 3 seconds. However, I haven't read all the specs ([animation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation), [transitions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#transition) ) and only got that from dummy tests.

Comment: I'll read them. But its just so confusing to me right know. And I think your explanation is a good starting point. I underestimated transitions.